# Multi module maven project with Quarkus in dev mode

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

I am not able to run my multi module project with quarkus in dev mode.

Here is my problem. We are currently switching from wildfly to quarkus on a multi module maven project. I am able to run quarkus in dev mode (with quarkus:dev) if I have only one quarkus module. But as soon as I have 2 modules the dev mode is not working.

Here is my root pom:

```
  <modules>
    <module>lib1</module>
    <module>quarkus-module1</module>
    <module>quarkus-module2</module>
  </modules>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
      <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-index</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>jandex</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>build</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin> 

  ...

  </plugins>
</build>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The pom.xml of the module lib1 (pure java project)

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

The pom of quarkus-module1

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The pom of quarkus-module2

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

When I run the following command on the root pom

```
mvn clean package quarkus:dev
```

Maven build lib1, quarkus-module1 and run quarkus-module1 in dev mode but it seems that querkus-module2 (build and dev mode) is blocked until dev mode of quarkus-module1 is stopped (with ctrl C).

**Is there a way to run quarkus-module1 and quarkus-module2 in dev mode at the same time ?**

I am using quarkus 2.15.3.Final with a JDK 11 (mandrel).
For information the two modules needs quarkus because in prod they are deployed in two distinct docker images and communicates using REST API.

As I said, I am able to run in dev mode with only lib1 and quarkus-module1 but as soon as I add quarkus-module2 I am not able to have simultaneously quarkus-module1 and quarkus-module2 in dev mode

Comment: "*Is there a way to run quarkus-module1 and quarkus-module2 in dev mode at the same time ?*" - Just open two terminals. In one, run `mvn -pl quarkus-module1 quarkus:dev`, in the other run `mvn -pl quarkus-module2 quarkus:dev`.

Comment: Ok I will try this tomorrow. Do I need an additional plugin/dependency for the argument -pl ?
However in my real case I have in fact 8 quarkus-module. Is there another way to run the 8 modules at the same time in dev mode without executing 8 commands ?

Comment: `pl` is a standard argument of `mvn`. It stands for "projects" and is basically the same as `cd`ing into the submodule-directory and running `mvn` there.  --- "*Is there another way to run the 8 modules at the same time in dev mode without executing 8 commands ?*" - Not that I know of. I recommend using an IDE with quarkus support (e.g. IntelliJ). Another way would be to containerize the application with remote-dev enabled. But this would require to start 8 remote-dev connections (i.e. eight commands), so nothing won here.

Comment: 6 years of using maven and I haven't heard for this argument of mvn . Ok it would be a nice improvement as I was able to do it with wildly and eclipse (using server view and adding my 8 modules)

Comment: It is a bit inconvenient but, to defend the Quarkus case, remember that with WildFly you have a single process, the application server, and 8 deployments. With Quarkus you have 8 distinct processes. Don't forget to change the web server port for each module too - otherwise there will be a port conflict! Good luck!